# I have a multiple sheets in an excel workbook. I need to scan all these sheets at the click of a button and pick specific values from the sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following tables in separate sheets (but same workbook):

Sheet 1
[image: Sample sheet 1]

Sheet 2
[image: Sample sheet 2]

Sheet 3
[image: Sample sheet 3]

In Sheet 4, I need to click the button. This button will scan sheet 1, 2 and 3 and provide a list of items that are have the value of Permanent column as "No". It has to be one single list in Sheet 4.

Expected Sheet 4:
[image: List in Sheet 4]

I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Can you please include what you have tried and what didn't work as expected? Also, you have both tagged VBA and Excel-Formula. Which one are you working on? Clicking a button implies you looking into VBA instead of formulas.

Comment: Copy all data from sheet1 to sheet3 into sheet4 and use AutoFilter in sheet4. • Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

This is far from a perfect solution, and it still needs some error handling to meet daily issues... however it should give you a good starting point on how to manipulate your data, and do so without reading back and forth from the spreadsheet multiple times (though for a couple of rows it doesn't matter, for few thounds it does).

```
Option Explicit

Sub getNonPermanents()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook         'or ThisWorkbook, or the name of the workbook where data is
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim R As Long, C As Long, X As Long
Dim lRow As Long

Dim arrData
Dim arrNonPerm() As String: ReDim arrNonPerm(1 To 3, 1 To 1)

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets()
        If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Or ws.Name = "Sheet2" Or ws.Name = "Sheet3" Then  'Or could just be ws.Name <> "Sheet 4", and/or other more elegant ways to deal with this
            lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row                     'Get the last row in the current sheet

            arrData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lRow, 3))               'Allocate all data to an array

            For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)                          'Loop through the data, and if any are "No"....
                If arrData(R, 3) = "No" Then
                    X = X + 1
                    ReDim Preserve arrNonPerm(1 To 3, 1 To X)                   'Increase the array as needed
                    For C = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                        arrNonPerm(C, X) = arrData(R, C)                        'Allocate to the non perm array
                    Next C
                End If
            Next R
        End If
    Next ws

    Erase arrData
    ReDim arrData(LBound(arrNonPerm, 2) To UBound(arrNonPerm, 2), LBound(arrNonPerm) To UBound(arrNonPerm))

    For R = LBound(arrNonPerm, 2) To UBound(arrNonPerm, 2)                      'Reallocate the data to an array to be ready to put it back in the sheet
        For C = LBound(arrNonPerm) To UBound(arrNonPerm)
            arrData(C, R) = arrNonPerm(R, C)
        Next C
    Next R

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet4")
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        .Range(.Cells(lRow + 1, 1), .Cells(lRow + UBound(arrData), 3)) = arrData    'Add the data at the end of existing data (i.e. headers the very least).
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastrowWS As Long, LastrowS4 As Long, i As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.name <> "Sheet4" Then

            With ws

                LastrowWS = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                For i = 2 To LastrowWS

                    If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No" Then

                        .Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Copy

                        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")

                            LastrowS4 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                            .Range("A" & LastrowS4 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                        End With

                    End If

                Next i

            End With

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Simple and doing what requested... and surely works for few rows fine. But if you have thousands of rows, this is doomed to get slower the bigger the data is. Ideally you should only access the sheets twice with VBA, read/write and use arrays to process everything in the background (at lighting speeds).

Comment: @DarXyde each answer should provide a way to go where you want. NOT the way especially when the OP ask for a code without providing any effort. if you need speed you should consider dictionary as the best solution.